# Getting loggedin user status passeportjs Nodejs

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am currently following a tutorial on user authntification using the mean stack :http://mherman.org/blog/2015/07/02/handling-user-authentication-with-the-mean-stack/#.WE2ff-bhCM8 .

But the author does not explain the following api route :

```
router.get('/status', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.isAuthenticated()) {
    return res.status(200).json({
      status: false
    });
  }
  res.status(200).json({
    status: true
  });
});
```

And the client side code :

```
function getUserStatus() {
  return $http.get('/user/status')
  // handle success
  .success(function (data) {
    if(data.status){
      user = true;
    } else {
      user = false;
    }
  })
  // handle error
  .error(function (data) {
    user = false;
  });
```

The author explain it is to get user status. But i want to know more can you give me an explanation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's simply that the `getUserStatus()` function sends a GET request to the server, the server checks whether the user is authenticated or not, and responds with either `status: true` or `status: false` accordingly. The getUserStatus function takes the response and set the user variable to true or false.

Answer (score 0):

On a `/status` route request from a user that isn't passport authenticated, the middleware in your first example sends a false value to the browser on status `200` AJAX request, which is a successful call.

I assume the second chunk of code uses the given value for set the user's permission to some control on the client side.